# Django: check a last character in string

Tags: python, django, string

I have this string `doc.specalization.name` from my views. If it does end with an `s`, I want to remove the `s`.

I tried this code but i get `Could not parse the remainder: '('s')' from 'doc.specialization.name.endswith('s')'`

```
 {% if doc.specialization.name.endswith('s') %}
        <h3> {{doc.specialization.name|slice:":-1"}} </h3>   
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Write a custom template tag.

Answer (score 4):

Karthikr's answer is close.  Ifequal is scheduled to be deprecated in future versions of Django, so you may want to use the method below.  You also need to add a ':' after the '-1'.

```
{% if doc.specialization.name|default:""|slice:"-1:" == "s" %}
  <h3> {{ doc.specialization.name|slice:":-1" }} </h3>
{% else %}
  <h3> {{ doc.specialization.name }} </h3>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is the up to date answer that works in django 2.2. Note the "you also need to add a ":" after the "-1"!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run python code in a django template. You can use a builtin filter for this:

```
{% ifequal doc.specialization.name|default:""|slice:"-1" "s" %}
    {# do your stuff #}
{% endifequal %}
```

The `default` is only a fallback for `None` values

Documentation on [`slice` here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)

You could even use the [`with` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#with) to avoid computing the same thing multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You're better off doing this in your view code than in a template. For example:

```
for doc in doc_records:
    if doc.specialization.name.endswith('s'):
        doc.specialization.name = doc.specialization.name[:-1]
```

But don't save the record, assuming this is just for display purposes

Comment: by doing this, you are replacing the existing data, which is probably not what OP wants. Did you mean to store it into another list ?